# Select xml attribute and node value in a single xml query ver 1.0

Tags: xml, xpath, attributes

I have:

```
<Node>
<Database>
    <Instance serverName="dbs030">
        <Name>SCOM</Name>
    </Instance>
    <Instance serverName="dbs031">
         <Name>SVGMGT</Name>
    </Instance>
</Database>
</Node>
```

and I need a single xpath to produce "dbs030\SCOM,dbs031\SVGMGT"

I have tried the following ...

/Node/Database/Instance/@serverName  | /Node/Database/Instance/Name/text()

> > dbs030,SCOM,dbs031,SVGMGT

concat(/Node/Database/Instance//@serverName,'\',/Node/Database/Instance/Name/text())

> > dbs030\SCOM

How do I get concat to continue through all instances

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. It has to be a single xpath statement. I am using an operation in HP Operation Orchastration and it only accepts a filepath and xpath statement as its 2 arguments

Comment: There is no way using XPath 1.0, AFAICS

Answer (score 0):

Concat uses only the first value from each argument. But you can make loop while found with

```
concat(//Database[1]/Instance/@serverName, "\", //Database[1]/Instance/Name)
concat(//Database[2]/Instance/@serverName, "\", //Database[2]/Instance/Name)
```